# Explanation of ethernet descriptor ring

Tags: ethernet

I'm writing firmware to configure the Ethernet module in Freescale's Vybrid 6xxx. I've been looking at this [site](http://beyond-syntax.com/blog/2011/03/diving-into-linux-networking-i/) to try to learn more about descriptor rings, but I still have a few questions.

What sort of data is stored in the descriptors? Additionally, what is the purpose of using a ring? How does the ring work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked many questions. I'll answer, not in the order asked.

1. Descriptor rings are a general concept, not specific to Freescale nor to Vybird. They are provided so that the user should be able to allocate memory ahead of time. Each descriptor gives a single command (i.e. a single Ethernet packet directive) to the controller.
2. In contrast to the concept of BD (buffer descriptor) rings which is general -- the implementation of any given BD ring is highly dependent on the hardware. As to the specific platform that you asked about, I refer you to section 42.5.13 in the [Reference Manual](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/VYBRIDRM.pdf?fsrch=1&sr=2)

Comment: Thanks, that mostly clears it up. Thanks for the datasheet link. I didn't know that Rev 4 had come out.